# Application fails to autheticate when deployed on glassfish server

Tags: java, deployment, glassfish

IDE: Jdevloper
Server: Glassfish

I have deployed ADF application on glassfish server, when I am trying to login application it does not authenticate. Same application was working on WebLogic 12 server and I was able to authenticate.

I am using Oracle database for connection and sure that there is no connection issue between application and Glassfish.

On the login page, I have a password in an encrypted format. if I change it to text then the application will authenticate.

I have already checked, a connection between database and application.
Also glassfish is able to ping the database with configured JNDI.
If I change password field to secret false then I can log in else it won't.

```html
<af:inputText label="Username" id="it34" columns="20" autoSubmit="true"
     contentStyle="font-family:-webkit-body;font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;"
     binding="#{backingBeanScope.LoginBean.userName}"/>
<af:inputText label="Password" id="it35" secret="true" columns="20" autoSubmit="true"
     contentStyle="font-family:-webkit-body;font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;"
    binding="#{backingBeanScope.LoginBean.passWord}"/>
```

Comment: Do you see some error on glassfish logs?

Comment: @admlz635 Thanks for the reply, Have checked. but sadly there are no error logs.